# I confuse with datatimepickers and datetimes. Need some help

Tags: c#, winforms

Need some your help.

I have two datetimepickers on my form: dt1 and dt2.

dt1 is for picking a date.

dt2 is for picking a time.

How can I get a *DateTime dt* where Date component is from dt1 and time component is from dt2 ?

**C#, .net 2.0**

Comment: @Teoman what was the point of adding .net as a tag?

Comment: @alex, sorry edited the wrong question, rolled it back. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the Date component from the value of `dt1` and the time component from the value of `dt2` and combine them with the `Add` method, like this:

```
DateTime theDate = dt1.Value.Date;
TimeSpan theTime = dt2.Value.TimeOfDay;

DateTime dt = theDate.Add(theTime);

// dt now contains date from dt1 and time from dt2
```